# Bootstrap 3 CSS image caption overlay

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, image-gallery

I use bootstrap and having a problem to overlay caption over an image, the caption div just cannot fit within the box, as shown below:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/upload/projects/21/wolf.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <p class="desc_content">The pack, the basic unit of wolf social life.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/upload/projects/21/cake.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        <div class="desc">
            <p class="desc_content">The pack, the basic unit of wolf social life.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.desc{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @himanshu to solved the issue.

```
div.desc{
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.fix{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: try using box-sizing: border-box; for p.desc_content class

Comment: @Vitorino Fernandes, No luck!

Comment: try remove width:100%  and add left:0; right:0; for div.desc

Comment: @Vitorino Fernandes, please view my edited post.

Comment: add left:0; right:0; for div.desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is in placement rather then overlay, `div.desc` is absolute and image is its sibling. So overlay will not follow image it will follow only anchor tag or your `div.wrapper`.

From what I can see is that there is a margin on image or padding in anchor or wrapper.

The best solution is to put `desc` and image in another `div` with 100% width with 0 padding.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 wrapper">
    <a href="#">
<div class="fix">
        <img src="images/upload/projects/21/wolf.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <p class="desc_content">The pack, the basic unit of wolf social life.</p>
        </div></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fix{width:100%; padding:0px;}
```

Comment: use div.desc{width:100%;}

Comment: give 
position: relative;

.fix{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

Answer (score 3):

For others trying to overlay a caption on an image in Bootstrap, consider using carousel captions.

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

```
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Chania</h3>
    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="">
        <img src="images/upload/projects/21/wolf.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
    </div>
    <div class="desc_content" style="">The pack, the basic unit of wolf social life.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="">
         <img src="images/upload/projects/21/wolf.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
    </div>
    <div class="desc_content" style="">The pack, the basic unit of wolf social life.</div>
 </div>
```

css

```
div.desc_content {
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
font: bold 11px verdana;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 7px;
height: 23px; opacity: 0.7;
position: relative; 
top: -30px;
}
div.wrapper{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this attributes for div.desc class

```
div.desc{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    left:0;   /** new  **/
    right:0;  /** new  **/
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me. With this you will find the caption at the bottom of the image.

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <img src="someimg.jpg" class="img-fluid " alt="Patience">   
    <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h1>Some label</h1>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want it at the top then in your CSS do the following:

```
.carousel-caption{
top:0;
bottom:auto;
}
```