# Bootstrap Overlay Text on Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay

I am trying to display overlay text on the Image using Bootstrap. I refereed the [Stack Overflow Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010257/bootstrap-3-css-image-caption-overlay). But Overlay is not fit into Image. I don't know What I have missed in that Answer

What I have tried [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10938/)

Thank You

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="DivOurProducts" class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 wrapper">
         <a href="/Article/Overview/1">
            <div class="fixOverlayDiv">
               <img alt="offer banner1" class="category-banner img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
               <div class="OverlayText">Text Here</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 wrapper">
         <a href="/Article/Overview/2">
            <div class="fixOverlayDiv">
               <img alt="offer banner1" class="category-banner img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
               <div class="OverlayText">Text Here</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 wrapper">
         <a href="/Article/Overview/3">
            <div class="fixOverlayDiv">
               <img alt="offer banner1" class="category-banner img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
               <div class="OverlayText">Text Here</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 wrapper">
         <a href="/Article/Overview/4">
            <div class="fixOverlayDiv">
               <img alt="offer banner1" class="category-banner img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
               <div class="OverlayText">Text Here</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixOverlayDiv{
    width:100%; 
    padding:0px;
}
.OverlayText{
     background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you can also use a carousel-caption. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446655/5876626

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an Answer. I have missed `Position = "relative"` for Parent Div

**CSS**

In fixOverlayDiv class added `Position = "relative"`

```
.fixOverlayDiv{
 position: relative;
 width:100%; 
 padding:0px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10948/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the css class to                                 .OverlayText{
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 20%;
    color: #fff;
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}

Comment: Its not clear what you want to achieve. You can use developer tools and check html and css classes. for eg. in chrome you can do F12 and see  details. Also you can right click text element on your page and select inspect element. You can modify the css and see changes. if you are trying to overlap text entirely on image try this( tested on Chrome browser)      .OverlayText{
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;  
    height:100%;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 82%;
    margin-left:15px; 
}   fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10947/

Comment: I am trying to do something like [this](https://phanivankadari.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/image_thumb.png)